# Reconnecting to wamp server with same configuration failed

Tags: wamp

I can't able to successfully connect to the wamp server from other machine from where I used to connect previously. With the same httpd.conf I connected successfully earlier. I turned of firewall and changed the httpd.conf file accordingly to connect from the other machine. I am facing the same issue continuously. Need suggestions to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first suggestion is that you post the required details. Your configuration. Your network setup. Your request that fails. The actual error message you get. You cannot expect us to somehow magically _guess_ what might be the case.

Comment: I am developing an iOS application that needs to connect to the MySQL database. So to that I have installed WAMP server. I have written php file that will sends the request to the database and sends back responds to the iOS application. As long as I tried to access the URL from the system where I installed WAMP server, I am not getting any problem. But when I tried to access the same URL from iOS application sometimes I can able to connect and some times not.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember WAMPServer is primarily a developer tool and as such is configured for the security of beginners. Apache is setup to only be accessible from the PC running WAMPServer.

If you want to allow access from other PC's i your network all you need to do is put it online.

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This will chnage the `httpd.conf` file to allow access from any ip, so as long as your network is not accessible form outside your network it is not a security issue.

Additional Info:

Possibly the "Put Online" has not worked, it sometimes happens if manual amendments have been made to the `httpd.conf` file. In that case make the amendments manually.

Edit `httpd.conf` using the wampmanager menus

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Find this section

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
</Directory>
```

And change the following part by adding the triplet for your local network subnet i.e. only the first 3 of the 4 quartiles and any ip in that subnet will be allowed access to apache

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

Alternatively, you can allow any ip in the universe

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
```

This is a little dangerous if your network can be accessed from the internet.

Also you will need to check your Firewall. You need to grant access on port 80 to external TCP access, and port 443 if you using SSL.

Comment: I kept the server online all the time but still having the same issue.